# How to add a where condition as parameter in stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I do not know whether it is possible or not.Whenever parameter id gets value it shows an error //Unknown table 'tbl_news' in field list

```
function select_table_img ($type,$eid)
    {
        if($b==NULL)
        {
            $id=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $id="tbl_news.nid='$eid'";
        }
        echo $sql = "CALL Proc_selectvideo('$type',$id)";//call the stored procedure
        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }
```

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Proc_selectvideo`(IN `type` VARCHAR(500), IN `id` VARCHAR(500))

select * from tbl_news,tbl_video where  tbl_news.nid  = tbl_video.cid and tbl_news.ntype=type and id
```

Comment: " and id?" ... I dont know your table fields but try to change last part of your query with this;  " and tbl_news.id=id"

Comment: i don't know is it a foolishness or not i am just reducing my code so that i need to use this same query for selecting all data as well as selecting a row of data .So that i have written last part like that if the id is null then it will return 1.else tbl_news.id='my row'.  @ B.Kocaman

Answer (score 0):

If I get understand, problem is single quote that you send from php.

> $id="tbl_news.nid='$eid'";

Maybe you can use IF statement or CASE for try different way to solve it in your stored procedure.

> $id=$eid;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Proc_selectvideo`(IN `type` VARCHAR(500), IN `id` VARCHAR(500))

DECLARE part_of_query VARCHAR(300) DEFAULT '';

SET part_of_query = CASE 
    WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(" AND tbl_news.nid='",id,"' ")
    ELSE 'maybe other parameter or rule...'
END;

select * from tbl_news,tbl_video where  tbl_news.nid  = tbl_video.cid and tbl_news.ntype=type part_of_query
```

Comment: I just executed your code but it shows an error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'part_of_query' . Can you please help me .Thanks @B.Kocaman

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to Declare that variable. I updated my answer.